# unable to retrieve data sent via ajax in controller Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, controller, laravel-5.1

I am sending data via ajax to my controller as

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: sessionStorage.getItem('user_id') },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"/*,
    success:function(id){
    alert(sessionStorage.getItem('user_id'));
}*/
});
```

and in the controller I am using

```
public function getUserMessages(){

        $id = Input::get('id');
        $messages = Message::where('message_by' , Auth::user()->id)->where('message_for',$id)->get();
        echo "id is ",$id;
        return $messages;
    }
```

I am getting nothing in `$id`. I have also tried `$_POST['id']` which says `undefined index id`. How I can retrive the id value?
`$request->has('id')` returns false too.

Comment: This is a silly question -> Did you set the user_id before getting it?

Comment: yes, I doubled check it. value is being set before sending and I can see the value being sent too. [link](http://prntscr.com/8b4nib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the application content as json, You don't need to set the content.

[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: sessionStorage.getItem('user_id') },
    dataType: 'json',

    success:function(data){
         console.log(data); // always good to output content for debugginn
    }
});
```

Hope this help. Your ajax should work now.

Comment: I had to also remove the `dataType`. But my ajax request is only working after I disable the csrf protection on the route. Otherwise I always get `500 internal server error`

Comment: @Adamnick add this to you script if you don't have it `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers : {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
   });
`

Comment: @Adamnick thanks for accepting the answer. good luck with the rest.

Comment: I have it but this keeps triggering the error and I am now sick of it. :/
One extra question, can i return a partial view from controller?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `Request` class instead of `Input`:

```
public function getUserMessages(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

        $id = $request->id;
        $messages = Message::where('message_by' , Auth::user()->id)->where('message_for',$id)->get();

        return $messages;
    }
```

Your ajax call doesn't work and will throw a 500 Server Error because you need to pass laravel's csrf token with it whenever you POST something. Create a meta tag at the top of your blade view like:

```
<meta name="_token_" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and get the value when you are doing the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        id: sessionStorage.getItem('user_id'),
        _token:document.getElementsByName('_token_')[0].getAttribute('content') 
    },
    success:function(id){
    alert(id);
}
});
```

Most likely the success function in your ajax call will only alert [object Object], to get a better overview over whats returned, use

```
console.log(id);
```

instead.

You may also create an error function for the ajax call so that possible errors will be shown. Just do add

```
error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

after the success function.

Comment: I have `<meta name="_token_" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in my master template header so request is being sent and the data too. I can see the data in chrome [link](http://prntscr.com/8b4nib). But the problem is I am injecting this controller in my view and calling the function so I have to pass the `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance there too. How do i do that?

Comment: Sorry  I don't understand what you mean. You can inject the `Request` class in all your controller methods without a problem if that's what you mean. @Adamnick

Comment: I am injecting like this `@inject('request','Illuminate\Http\Request')` and passing $request to my function call. but unfortunately still not getting the value.

Comment: why do you do this? I wouldn't inject the controller into the view. If you need data from the controller in your view, use `return view('View')->with(['foo' => $foo]);` instead.

Comment: i do not want to return a view since the view where i need the data is chat box a partial.

Comment: I have added both parts sending the data and receiving it. In the function I am echoing the $id but it is empty. So there is no point looking into the view.

Comment: are you sure that there is data in the table for the given wheres?

Comment: `echo "id is ",$id;` should return the value in the function. Yes there is data in the db.

Comment: Please change the comma to a dot: echo "id is " . $id; That's a syntax error, didn't see that..

Comment: nope that is not the problem. I am not getting the value even [link](http://prntscr.com/8b500n)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88415/discussion-between-adam-nick-and-michael).

Comment: `$request->has('id') ` is returning false too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you a route for AJAX requests? (I don't see it.)

Please try following code:

In your AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('ajax_route') }}",
    data: { _token:  "{{ csrf_token() }}", data: "sample data" },
    success: function(data){
        $(".result").html(data);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

In your controller code:

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request){
  if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('post')) {
    $data = $request->input('data', null);
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

In your route code:

```
Route::post('/ajax_route', ['as' => 'ajax-action', 'uses' => 'YourController@ajaxAction']);
```

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford; Thanks for correction sorry my bad english :)

Comment: No worries: that's why there are help, improvement and editing queues.